# What is the exact impact of following content of `.gitignore` file in one of subdirectories?

Tags: git, gitignore

What is the exact impact of the following content of `.gitignore` file in one of the subdirectories:

```
*

!.gitignore
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` means "everything". `!` is the negation operator. So basically, this means ignore everything except the `.gitignore` file. Or another words, ignore everything in this directory except the fact that you're ignoring everything.